# Views show child taxonomy terms

Tags: drupal, view

I have a vocabulary like this:

```
Parent 1
- Child 1
- Child 2
- Child 3
Parent 2
- Child 1
- Child 2
```

Now i would like to use a view to create a list of all the child terms under one parent.
So i thought i just created a term Views and pass the Parent term as an argument and it will filter out all the child terms of that parent.
But this doesn't seem to be possible with the standard views.

The only thing that's possible is to get the parent term when you supply the child term, but not the other way around.

Anyone an idea how i can do this?

Answer (score 6):

The Views module has a  `taxonomy_term` View which you can use.  You need to edit the View so that under the `Arguments` -> `Taxonomy: Term ID (with depth)` -> change the depth so that you can grab as many levels of child objects as you want.  If you want to exclude the parent item, you can do this by adding a filter to exclude the parent term.

Comment: The problem with this that when i have more that 1 node attached to a child term, it appears more than once in the list. One time for every node that has this child tag as a tag. I tried the distinct setting but it doesn't help.

Comment: what settings do you change? How does this make the view display terms instead of nodes?

Comment: @jdln - This does not create a view which displays terms instead of nodes.  It creates a view with nodes which belong to parent AND children terms instead of just nodes which belong to the parent term only.

Comment: The question was about displaying terms not nodes. There is no "Taxonomy: Term ID (with depth)" within term views.

Answer (score 0):

There is an filter argument for "Taxonomy term: Parent term"

If you set that to bee less than 1. You will only get root elements in your taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick solution, go to `admin/structure/views/import`, import below views and update views according to your requirement.

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'locations2';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$view->human_name = 'Product Categories';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Product Categories';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['distinct'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['pure_distinct'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'grid';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Taxonomy term: Parent term */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['parent']['id'] = 'parent';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['parent']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_hierarchy';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['parent']['field'] = 'parent';
/* Field: Global: View result counter */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['id'] = 'counter';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['field'] = 'counter';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['label'] = '#';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['counter_start'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['counter']['reverse'] = 1;
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['link_to_taxonomy'] = TRUE;
/* Filter criterion: Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['id'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_vocabulary';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['field'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['relationship'] = 'parent';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['operator'] = 'not empty';

/* Display: Product Categories List */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Product Categories List', 'block_2');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'counter' => 'counter',
  'name' => 'name',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'counter' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'name' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
```